# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException with IE

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer

I am working on a relatively complex asp.net web forms application, which loads user controls dynamically within update panels. I've run into a very peculiar problem with Internet Explorer where after leaving the page idle for exactly one minute you receive a `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException` javascript exception when the next request is made. This doesn't happen in Firefox and Chrome. When the server receives the bad request, the body is actually empty but the headers are still there. The response that is sent back is a fresh response you would get from a `GET` request, which is not what the update panel script is expecting. Any requests done within a minute are okay. Also any requests made following the bad request are okay as well.

I do not have any response writes or redirects being executed. I've also tried setting `ValidateRequest` and `EnableEventValidation` in the page directive. I've looked into various timeout properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resided with how IE handles NTLM authentication protocol. An optimization in IE that is not present in Chrome and Firefox strips the request body, which therefore creates an unexpected response for my update panels. To solve this issue you must either allow anonymous requests in IIS when using NTLM or ensure Kerberos is used instead. The KB article explains the issue and how to deal with it.[KB251404](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=251404)